# What to call a book that does not get a lot of readers?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some books do not get a lot of readers; they are not read by many. Sometimes because they are not that good, sometimes because they are not advertised enough, or perhaps for other reasons, they are kind of isolated in the world of readers. What to call such books?

Comment: Mao's little read book

Comment: You could call them ***obscure*** (or even ***rare***) books, but that might carry implications of "challenging to understand" (or "much sought-after, highly-prized"). Perhaps your best bet is ***neglected books***, but in practice that always implies *unjustly* [much-]neglected (in the writer's / speaker's opinion, they're well worth reading, and more people *should* read them). Or just be a bit loose and call them ***remaindered*** books (copies the bookshops couldn't sell at their target price).

Comment: Sasan, actually @Mitch is on to something (and should post an answer). "Little-read" is probably ideal because it cuts through the various reasons a book might not be read much.

Comment: I agree with @Mitch. This is the best (obvious) answer. It also states a simple fact rather than making some kind of judgment (which could easily be wrong).

Comment: ......A thesis :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**little read**  [F. Times UK](https://www.ft.com/content/0b312510-30f6-11e8-b5bf-23cb17fd1498)  An article:

> Dictator Literature by Daniel Kalder — little-read books

And an earlier ( 1876 ) sense of 'garnering few readers':  [google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=bL0jp26MUpAC&dq=%22little%20read%22&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q=%22little%20read%22&f=false)

> The second reason why history is so **little read** is on account of its
>   not being taught ...

Answer (score 3):

as pointed out, **little-read** or **obscure** are obvious choices with little to no bias to them.

If, instead you wanted to connote that a book has not been read by many because it is a failure, you could refer to it as a **flop** or a **nonstarter**.

Conversely, you could connote that a good book has not been read much by calling it **underrated** or **underappreciated**.

Finally, media which is not necessarily rare or unknown but has a relatively small and fervent following is often said to be a **[cult classic](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/2522.Cult_Classics)**